# How to send stream on Azure Media service Secondary INGEST URL by RTMP?

Tags: azure, ffmpeg, rtmp

I did well to post stream on Primary INGEST URL, but failed to post stream on Secondary INGEST URL.

I uesd FFMPEG to post stream, i found that FFMPEG stuck while handshaking with Azure Media service.

I saw FFMPEG send 0x0C and 1536 random bytes to Azure Media service, but Azure didn't response anything.

Is Secondary INGEST URL still work?